# How do we track offline marketing traffic to my website using Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, tracking, marketing

Suppose I want to track my website traffic those who are coming from my offline marketing such as pamphlet and hoarding or any other physical activity.

I have installed Google Analytics and webmaster on the website.
If it is possible, let me know the proper setting and part in Google Analytics.

Comment: Campaign tracking in Google Analytics is done with UTM parameters on the URLs: https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/campaign-url-builder/   Because those URLs are hard to type, you will probably want to implement short URLs that redirect to add the UTM parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Offline campaign is not hard to track but you need to make sure that you don't pollute/mix the campaign url with other traffic sources.

For instance you can create a special url which is not available from other pages of your website (to make sure you don't get visitors from other sources). You should set that single url to noindex to avoid getting indexed by search engines. Make sure you have analytics tracking enabled on that page. This can be the campaign url and landing page. You can also redirect all users arriving to that url so they end up on the "common" campaign page. When you do the redirect you inject url variables : campaign tracking so you get nice and clean data in goigle analytics.

Another way of doing this is with a separate domain or subdomain for the offline campaign only. Same rules apply as above i.e. don't let it get indexed or you will start getting organic traffic.

You can of course use qr codes in combination to make it easy and fun.